# Empty lxc core dump

Tags: linux, coredump, lxc

Good day.
I cannot achieve getting core dump file of any process launched from lxc container.
Here are my settings (inside container):

> $ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
>   /var/crash/coredump-%e.%p
>
> $ ulimit -c
>   unlimited
>
> $ ls -lha /var/crash/
>   drwxrwxrwx  2 root     root     13 Oct 14 23:34 .
>   ...

I start a C-written program that causes core dump inside container:

> $ ./c
>   Segmentation fault

And don't get a message "core dumped" (unlike in base system, outside container everything is just perfect).
But a new file is generated in core dump path and it has a zero size:

> $ ls -lha /var/crash/*
>   -rw------- 1 root root 0 Oct 14 23:43 /var/crash/coredump-c.1866

This behavior is similar for php5-fpm process, it also generates a zero-sized core dump when crashes, yet the limit for the pool is set to "unlimited" in pool settings.

Is there anything I've missed? Exploring the Internet for something like "limits lxc" or "core dump lxc" didn't get me anything relevant. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Having the same issue.